# Dismiss keyboard of TextField programmatically

Tags: iphone, objective-c, keyboard, textfield, resignfirstresponder

I know how to use the following method by Interface Builder.

```
-(void)dismissKeyboard 
{
    [testTextField resignFirstResponder];
}
```

In this way, when I touch the area outside the keyboard or tap the "return", the keyboard will dismiss.

But I don't know how to make it all by code. Please teach me , thanks.

Here's .h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController 
{
    UITextField *testTextField;
}

@property (nonatomic,retain) UITextField *testTextField;
@end
```

here's .m

```
#import "SecondViewController.h"
@implementation SecondViewController 
@synthesize testTextField;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];    

    UITextField *tempTextField = [[UITextField alloc] init];
    self.testTextField = tempTextField;
    testTextField.frame = CGRectMake(100, 150, 200, 30);
    testTextField.placeholder = @"Test";
    testTextField.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    testTextField.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [self.view addSubview:testTextField];

}
```

Comment: You didn't set the delegate..
`[tempTextField setDelegate:self];`

Comment: @DefenestrationDay yours is the right answer!

Answer (score 3):

What you lack is the `UITextFieldDelegate` with it comes a lot of textfield methods that will be called for different reasons.

Check out the apple docs!
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html

You should resign your keyboard in the

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

use this code in viewdidload

```
 UITapGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(hideKeyboard)];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];
  } 

 - (void) hideKeyboard 
  {
[textfieldname1 resignFirstResponder];
    [textfieldname2 resignFirstResponder];
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `UITextFieldDelegate` to your header and implement this delegate method:

```
textFieldShouldEndEditing:
```

resign your first responder in the method.