# iPhone: UITextField End Editing event doesn't hide keyboard

Tags: iphone, keyboard, uitextfield, hide, uitextfielddelegate

I want to hide keyboard on `UITextField` end editing event but somehow I am not able to get following code working! When I press Done button, it hides the keyboard but not when I don't press done button and move to another `UITextField` where I don't need keyboard but `UIPickerView`. Basically `UIPickerView` is appearing but behind the keyboard. I am resigning current `UITextField` on end editing event as well as on begin editing for required text fields. The begin editing code works fine if I don't have keyboard already shown for previous `UITextField`. Could someone please tell me what am I doing wrong?

Following sequence works:

1. Select normal `UITextField` and insert text, press done button (this hides keyboard)
2. Select picker `UITextField` (this displays picker view)

..but following doesn't:

1. Select normal `UITextField` and insert text
2. Select picker `UITextField` (the picker view is behind the keyboard as I didn't press done button for previous `UITextField`). Here it calls end editing but it doesn't hide keyboard!

   ```
   - (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
       [textField resignFirstResponder];
       scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 750);
       [scrollView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
       return YES;
    }

   -(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField  
   {
       [textField resignFirstResponder];
   }

   - (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
       DatePicker.hidden = YES;
       CountryPickerView.hidden = YES;

       switch (textField.tag) {
           case 3:
               [textField resignFirstResponder];
               DatePicker.hidden = NO;
               return;
           case 6:
               [textField resignFirstResponder];
               CountryPickerView.hidden = NO;
               return;
           default:
               break;
       }
       scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 650);
       [scrollView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 260)];
   }
   ```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dismiss keyboard of TextField programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7912586/dismiss-keyboard-of-textfield-programmatically)

Comment: Hi Celeb, I went through all the similar questions about hiding keyboard for uitextfield on stackoverflow but none of them is related to hiding keyboard and displaying something else(in my case it's uipicker). Everyone says it's just calling resignFirstResponder but in my case it's bit different logic to get it working. I have posted a solution. Thanks to Valexa!

Comment: No need to add the solution to the question. In fact, if you want to answer your own question, the right thing to do is to write it in an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> it hides the keyboard but not when I don't press done button and move
>   to another uitextfield where I don't need keyboard but PickerView.

The right way to handle this is to set the `inputView` property for the field that uses a picker instead of the keyboard. Configure the picker as you need it (set up delegate, data source, etc.) and then set it as the field's `inputView`. The system will handle hiding the keyboard and showing the picker view, or vice versa, as you move from one field to the next.

Comment: Can you please elaborate more by showing some code?

Comment: @GaneshGuturi Which part is unclear? Keep in mind that this question is nearly 5 years old.

Answer (score 10):

You should not be relying on tags but pointers to the objects and remove `[textField resignFirstResponder];` from textFieldDidEndEditing.

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField 
{ 
    if (textField == theTextFieldIDontWantKeyboardFor) {  
        [thepreviousTextField resignFirstResponder]; 
        return NO;
    }
    return YES; 
}
```

Comment: Hi Valexa, I added that to hide the keyboard! If I remove then also it doesn't work!

Comment: I do that because I don't textfield to be selected as I want user to select value from Picker view! If I remove from begin editing then keyboard will definitely appear which is I don't want. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: @velexa buddy I already spent lot of time to resolve this and figuring out what are the events sequences and etc but not able to get this around. The simple question would be how to dismiss keyboard when you switch to other textfield without pressing done button and don't show keyboard for newly selected textfield?

Comment: hahaha...we back to square..that was the first solution I tried! I kept that code in end edit event but doesn't work!

Comment: Whatever I do it seems this is something mystery of Apple! Can you try this simple code! It's fun!

Comment: - (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    if (textField == theTextFieldIDontWantKeyboardFor) return NO; [thepreviousTextField resignFirstResponder];   return YES;
}

Comment: Hmmm......that did the trick with little changes! See the solution. Thank you very much!

Comment: how to get `thepreviousTextField` if my textfield is in tableview and with no outlets

Comment: Thanks bro..saved my time and this could be the correct answer

Answer (score 3):

```
[yourTextField resignFirstResponder];
```

Is what actually hides the keyboard, so use that when the picker is about to open.

Comment: I am using this method in end editing! it doesn't hides the keyboard...also I am using same method in textFieldShouldReturn which is working(hiding keyboard) when I press Done button!!

Comment: The method textFieldDidEndEditing gets called *after the keyboard is already disappearing* so it makes no sense to tell it to disappear in this method.

Answer (score 3):

when you switch control from one textfield to next without resigning, `textFieldDidBeginEditing` does not get called so, you need to resign the textfield by making it "firstResponder" (as it is not firstResponder due to change in the active textfield) then calling `resignFirstResponder`

Comment: I am resigning the first one in end editing text! I have confirmed that when I switch to another textfield without pressing done the event sequences are "End editing first", "Resigning first", "Begin editing second"....every where I am resigning the first responder but still keyboard is not disappearing!!!

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
 -(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField  
  {
  if(textField==nameTextField){
    [nameTextField resignFirstResponder];

     //
  }
  else if(textField==pickerTextField){

  ///
  }
  }

  - (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
  if(textField==nameTextField){
    [nameTextField resignFirstResponder];

    //
  }
  else if(textField==pickerTextField){

  ///
  }
  }
```

Comment: that's what my code does! it doesn't work in end editing but does work in textFieldShouldReturn!!

Comment: This answer isn't correct. textFieldDidEndEditing is only called when the UITextField is already dismissing the keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Adding here my final outcomes!

Solution by Valexa. This worked absolutely fine but I needed to handle different input views manually.

```
    - (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
        [textField resignFirstResponder];
            scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 750);
            [scrollView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
        return YES;
    }

    - (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {    
           previousTextField = textField;
           scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 650);
           [scrollView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 260)];
    }

    - (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
           if (textField == CountryTextField || textField == BirthdayTextField) {
                  [previousTextField resignFirstResponder]; 
                  return NO; 
           }
          return YES; 
    }
```

Amazing solution(Thanks Caleb): No need to monitor extra variable for previous textfield and no need of having headache of showing and adding require views

```
BirthdayTextField.inputView = DatePickerView;
CountryTextField.inputView = CountryPickerView;
SexTextField.inputView = SexPickerView;

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
[textField resignFirstResponder];
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 750);
    [scrollView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
return YES;
}

- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 650);
    [scrollView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 260)];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)hidekeybord
{
    [_txt_fname resignFirstResponder];
    [_txt_lname resignFirstResponder];
    [_txt_email resignFirstResponder];
    [_txt_phoneN resignFirstResponder];
    [_txt_dateofbd resignFirstResponder];
    [_txt_address resignFirstResponder];
    [_txt_city resignFirstResponder];

}

- (IBAction)btn_open_datepiker:(id)sender
{
    [self hidekeybord];

    _datepiker_bd.hidden=FALSE;
    _toolbar_db.hidden=FALSE;


}
```